# multiple inserts using word userform

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been trying to create this userform automated template in Word. I would need to insert the same value several times in the form. I tried insert the same bookmark in three different places. That didn't work. Then I tried to re-use the same vba Lbl vlaue to be inserted in three different places, refered to with three different bookmarks. That does not seem to work either. Any suggestions? Thx. P.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far by posting your code.

Comment: You can't insert the same bookmark in 3 places, much like you can't place the same marker in 3 different places in a physical book. It's in the nature of a bookmark that it marks one place. You can use the text found at a bookmark in 3 different places of a userform. Help would be possible if you were to specify your meaning of "places".

Answer (score 0):

To test this you will need a `Userform` with name `Userform1` and then 3 `Labels` with names `CostLabel1`, `CostLabel2` and `CostLabel3`.

```
Sub PopulateUserForm()

    'Using CostPerItem as a example
    Dim CostPerItemText As String

    CostPerItemText = "$15"

    'Having set the names of the labels
    UserForm1.CostLabel1.Caption = CostPerItemText
    UserForm1.CostLabel2.Caption = CostPerItemText
    UserForm1.CostLabel3.Caption = CostPerItemText
    UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```